# jQuery .get() looping for all hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, get

```
$(function() {
   $.get('/viewonline',function(data) {
      var members = $('a.username');
      var location = $('a.location');
      var elems = $(data);
for (var i=0; i<members.length;i++) {
   var uname = members[i].text();
   var aname = members[i].href;
 $('.userlist_online').html('<a href="'+ aname +'">'+ uname +'</a>');
}
for (var j=0;j<location.length;j++) {
   var locaname= location[j].text();
   var locaaname = location[j].href;
 $('.userlist_views').html('<a href="'+ locaaname +'">'+ locaname +'</a>');
  }
 },'html');
});
```

The code above I am trying to loop through all the `a hrefs` with classes of `username` and `location`. So the code above doesn't throw any errors yet it is not posting any data into the divs.

Any one can help me figure out what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you possibly jsfiddle this so I can see the HTML that accompanies it?

Comment: Problems here: (1) `data` is not used anywhere. It is wrapped as `elems`, but `elems` is not used anywhere. (2) You're calling `$('.userlist_online').html(..)` in a loop. Every time you call that, it replaces the entire contents of `.userlist_online` - it doesn't append to what's already there. (3) You're doing `members[i].text();`, but `members[i]` is not a jQuery object so it doesn't have the `text()` method. I'm surprised this doesn't throw an error, but maybe `members` is empty so the line never executes.

Comment: you should use $(members[i]).text() and $(location[j]).text()

Comment: @tcovo yes that is what I am saying, I was getting an object error then messed around with the code more and it never threw a error. So this is why I am confused now. and my vars should be outside of the loop?
@George ok so don't use the var locaname =$(location[j]).text() instead? 
  Sorry guys not very good at .get() and loops. the elems was first used for this
  `$('.userlist_views').html(elems.find(location[i]));` So not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my guess at what will work:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('/viewonline', function (data) {

        data = $(data);
        var members = data.find('a.username');
        var location = data.find('a.location');

        for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
            var uname = $(members[i]).text();
            var aname = members[i].href;
            $('.userlist_online').append('<a href="' + aname + '">' + uname + '</a>');
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < location.length; j++) {
            var locaname = $(location[j]).text();
            var locaaname = location[j].href;
            $('.userlist_views').append('<a href="' + locaaname + '">' + locaname + '</a>');
        }
    }, 'html');
});
```

Fixes done:

- **get `members` and `location` by finding elements in the returned data, not in the current document.**
- wrap Elements with `$()` before calling `text()`
- use `append` instead of `html` when filling the lists

Comment: Worked Great Actually! Thank you and I loved the notes on what you did. I really appreciate it!